# Generating PDF using QPrinter (Qt, PySide), content unintentionally printed by physical printer

Tags: python, qt, pdf, printing

I have a desktop application written in Python which use Qt (PySide) for its GUI.

A feature of my application is displaying reports to the user, by supplying the report content (generated in HTML) to a [QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html).

This reporting feature also allows the user to export the report to a pdf. To achieve this, I have used the [QPrinter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html) class.
Here is an example:

```
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setOutputFileName('test.pdf')
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape)        
printer.setFullPage(True)

self.webview.print_(printer)
```

The PDF output is fine. However sometimes the content is also printed to a physical printer if there is one present, which is not intended.

I have looked through the documentation and can't find a solution to this. Please help.